# Flow direction and catchment area polygons for utility water pipes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, watershed, catchment-area, flow

I'm working on a project where I need to show which direction the water would flow from a water pipe in case there is a pipe burst.  I also need to show catchment polygons(area affected).  This was previously done by someone else and I'm doing it from a fresh start.  I've attached a screenshot showing a sampling of the previous work.  The blue/grey line is the water pipe, the red outline shows the polygons/area affected and the blue arrows show the flow direction.

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.2 and Spatial Analyst.  I have access to contour line data as well as the water pipe data.  I've done a little bit of googling and have seen a lot of information on watersheds, however, I think this project is the opposite of watershed analysis where instead of showing drainage towards a water channel/pipe, I need to show drainage away from a water channel/pipe.  I'm quite familiar with ArcGIS Desktop but pretty green to Spatial Analyst.  I can perform watershed analysis using various tutorials online but as I said, I think my analysis requires showing the opposite of watershed analysis, I think.  I need some help being pointed in the right direction as far as steps/tools to use.

[image: Previous Work]

[image: Sample data I'm working with]

[image: Corrected DEM]

[image: Results]

Comment: Where do those arrows come from?  They don't appear to be D8 flow pointers.  They almost appear to be flow pointers from a model, like a ground water model or something.  Any idea?

Comment: The arrows come from a point feature class.  The arrow rotation is based on the "grid_code" field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a hydrologically corrected (depressionless) DEM from your contours through interpolation to a raster DEM. Then you need to perform a flow accumulation operation, such that the pipes serve as the seed points and the downslope flowpaths issuing from these locations are traced. Many GIS have specific tools to perform this type of flowpath tracing operation but in ArcGIS, your best bet is to use the **[Flow Accumulation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000051000000.htm)** tool and to specify your pipes network as the weight raster. Before you can do this however you'll need to rasterize your pipes vector layer to a grid of the same dimensions as your DEM/flow pointer raster. The result will be be a Boolean raster where cells containing a pipe will have a value of 1 and all non-pipe cells will have a zero value. If you use this for your weight raster, the output of the flow accumulation tool should be the downstream flowpaths issuing from each pipe grid cell, and therefore the dispersal areas for your pipe network.

Comment: Thanks for the response. These are the steps I've done so far.

Comment: Thanks for the response. These are the steps I've done so far.
1. Convert contour lines to raster(DEM) using “Topo to Raster” tool.
2. Hydrologically correct the DEM using “Fill” tool.
3. Use “Polyline to Raster” tool on the water pipes.
4. Use “Flow Accumulation” tool.
I'm not getting the desired results.  When rasterizing the water pipes, it requires a "value". I'm not sure what I should be using here and perhaps thats causing the problem.

Comment: @steve you should **edit** your question (link at the lower left of it) to provide additional information. And rather than linking to offsite images, embed them in the post - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Edited question with additional screenshots corresponding to my comments here.

Comment: @Steve I'd just create a new field in your pipe's attribute table and fill it with 1's. Then use this new field as your value in the rasterization process. Either that, or you could also use the FID and then simply reclass the resulting raster pipes grid to be a Boolean.

Comment: When I perform the steps above and then convert the final product (from the Flow Accumulation tool) to a vector point file, the grid_code field has a zero value for all its features.  I was expecting it to be populated and to use those values to show direction flow based on the rotation symbology.

Comment: I've used the following steps outlined below to get half of what I need, which are direction points. I now need to figure out areas affected by a pipe burst. It seems to be this would the opposite of the watershed tool where watershed tool would calculate inward flow area, I need outward flow area?
1. Convert contours to DEM “Topo to Raster” tool.
2. Correct the DEM for any sinks using “Fill” tool.
3. Use “Flow Direction” on DEM.
4. Convert Flow Direction DEM to point and rotate points based on grid code to get flow direction.

Comment: @Steve No, the last step for you is flow accumulation...that is what you use to trace flowpaths. Particularly if you feed it a weight raster consisting of your pipes, that will work nicely. There's no need to modify the flow directions.

Comment: When I use the Flow Accumulation tool with the corrected DEM and the pipes as the weight raster, I just get a black raster as shown in the last screenshot above.  Do I need to perform further steps? Ultimately I need a polygon end product that shows all the area affected by outflow.

Comment: NM, I think i've got it.  Thanks for your help, WhiteboxDev :)

Comment: @Steve Fantastic, I'm very glad it worked out.

Comment: One follow-up.  I converted the Flow Direction ouput raster to points.  Now how do I display the direction of each point using arrow symbology?  Under the rotation properties I'm using the grid_code field.  My questions are, should I be using the geographic or arithmetic rotation style and what should the default arrow direction be set to?